# Android Studio freezes when adding UI element

Tags: android-studio

Running Android Studio 1.0.2 for Windows

Using a new Blank Activity or Blank Activity with Fragment project (bug happens with both). Haven't modified anything in the code yet. Using API 10: Android 2.3.3

Often immediately, sometimes shortly after I drag or edit my first/any UI element into activity_main.xml, Android Studio freezes and I have to close the process in task manager to get it to close.

I notice that in Task Manager the Android Studio Windows Launcher is taking about 25-30% of my CPU while its frozen.

What's going on here? Any ideas?

....

I may have found a solution for this.

I theorized that perhaps it was just the windows display that was frozen (the visual rendering of the Android Studio program itself) and guessed that perhaps this was using a DirectX device to do the rendering of the Android UI.

I happen to have another app running on my computer that uses a DirectX device for rendering (SimpleJungleTimer, an app I programmed with a DirectX overlay for League of Legends jungle timers). After I shut down this app Android Studio appears to be working properly (not freezing when working with the UI anymore)

Ultimately it sounds like this is a bug with Android Studio itself where they don't properly kill / reload the DirectX rendering device when it is in conflict with another app's active DirectX device (something that the android studio developers should probably fix), however until the android studio developers fix this you should be able to **get around this bug by making sure any other applications that might use DirectX for rendering are shut down while coding in Android Studio** so that their DirectX rendering devices don't conflict with Android Studio's DirectX device.